# Explanation of $\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E}=-\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}$

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields

If we have a static charge distribution, then $\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{E}=\vec{0}$, what if we now let that charge distribution to move with a constant velocity, how is this gonna affect the curl of their electric field? Would it change the above equation to $\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{E}=-\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t}$ ? But let's assume the current produced as a result of moving the charge distribution is steady, hence $\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t}=0$ so even in such a case $\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{E}=\vec{0}$ Is my reasoning currect? Is $\vec{B}$ in the aforementioned equation is the field produced by the charge distribution when in motion?

Comment: You're facing one of the simplest relativity effects. We think at $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ as vectors fields in classical electromagnetism, but they appear in a 2nd order 4D tensor in Einstein's relativity, that follows Lorentz's transformations for observers in uniform relative motion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A charge distribution moving with constant velocity is a DC current. We could have for example a circuit with a battery and a lamp. The curl of the E-field is zero. In this case, the E-field is minus the gradient of the potential.

If there is a moving magnet close to the circuit for example, the Maxwell equation of the title applies, and between the total magnetic and electric fields.